# How is an OPC-UA server managing EURange of a value?

Tags: opc-ua

The EURange is [described here](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Amendment1/5.3.2/).

> EURange defines the value range likely to be obtained in normal
>   operation. It is intended for such use as automatically scaling a bar
>   graph display.
>
> Sensor or instrument failure or deactivation can result in a returned
>   item value which is actually outside of this range. Client software
>   must be prepared to deal with this possibility. Similarly a Client may
>   attempt to write a value that is outside of this range back to the
>   server. The exact behaviour **(accept, reject, clamp, etc.)** in this case
>   is Server-dependent. However, in general Servers shall be prepared to
>   handle this.

**My question**: If a variable in an OPC-UA server has a defined the EURange to "**clamp**" (upper and lower limits has been set), what will happen if a client writes a value that is out of the range, to the defined server variable?

Let's say EU low: 0 and EU high: 100

A clients tries to set the variable to 101. Is the OPC-UA server then supposed to automatically correct the value to the closest limit (i.e. EU high: 100)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's appropriate for the server to either:

- reject the write and return StatusCode `Bad_OutOfRange`
- accept the write, clamp the value, and return StatusCode `Good_Clamped`

Answer (score 0):

The boundaries of an EURange are *advisory* in nature. It is okay for the server to clamp, but it is also fine to set the value to the contents of the Write Request argument (or another custom clamp, if that got exceeded, too) and optionally emit an Alarm on range violation.

Example: if you monitor the water level of a basin based on inflow calculus, you don't want the level to clamp on overflow. You want a flooding alarm.